# Microsoft VSTS burndown chart similar to Atlassian JIRA burndown

Tags: azure-devops, jira, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to get detailed burndown of subtasks rolled up to parent task as in [Atlassian JIRA burndown chart](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/burndown-chart-777002653.html), using Microsoft VSTS?

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t included in built-in burndown chart.

You can add a custom dashboard widget with REST API to meet the detail requirement through VSTS extension: [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=vsts#part-2-hello-world-with-vsts-rest-api)